# Firebase messaging in Unity does not change package name in built android manifest

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a project that gets built on Unity cloud builds with two package names, one is a com.company.name and one is a development build with com.company.name.dev. however, when building the dev build I am stuck with the com.company.name in the manifest and on some of the permissions created in the manifest this creates a conflict that you cannot install the two build on the same device as they have conflicting redeclaration of these permissions. note that this is an issue with Firebase Unity integration as other plugins such as Appsflyer do not cause this conflict and do properly change their declarations accordingly. did anyone else encounter this and can you suggest a way to fix this?

edit:

`permission
        android:name="com.company.game.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="0x2" />
uses-permission
        android:name="com.company.game.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />`

this is the area that does not change accordingly in the built manifest, this is from the dev build.

edit2:
this appears to be a problem related to unity cloud build and I think the android resolver. I am trying to force the resolution from code pre-build but the problem persists.

Comment: Without seeing more of how you have this setup all I can do is guess, but we use post process scripts for this and rewrite the manifest when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try invoking the play services resolver manually to see if that fixes your issue Under Assets/Play Services Resolver/Android Resolver/Resolve.
[Play Services Resolver Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woh5o.png)

You can read more about how the resolver works here: https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver

The Play Services Resolver seems to catch this in the latest plugin (5.6.0) although I do have to hit "Save" before it runs.